# How Can I Check To See If App was Started From A CD/DVD in C#?

Tags: c#

How Can I Check To See If App was Started From A CD/DVD in C#?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to know? Also, you should be aware of things like DAEMON tools, which mount a CD or DVD image as if it were a drive. I don't know how much like a CD/DVD drive DAEMON tools looks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the path where the exe was start from with Application.StartupPath property.
then use new DriveInfo(driveletter_from_path).DriveType to determine whether it is a CD or harddisk.

Comment: You'd probably want the executable path, not the startup path (which could be anything, regardless of where the program is).

Comment: Nice info on DriveInfo class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like that :

```
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        DriveInfo drive = new DriveInfo(file.Directory.Root.ToString());
        switch (drive.DriveType)
        {
            case DriveType.CDRom:
                MessageBox.Show("Started from CD/DVD");
                break;
            case DriveType.Network:
                MessageBox.Show("Started from network");
                break;
            case DriveType.Removable:
                MessageBox.Show("Started from removable drive");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on codemanix's answer:

```
string location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
DriveInfo info = new DriveInfo(Path.GetPathRoot(location));
if (info.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Started from CD-ROM");
}
```

[MSDN: description of the drive types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the executable path and see if it is on the CD/DVD drive. You can get the executable path with this:

```
string path = Application.ExecutablePath;
```

Comment: And how will you know if a path is on a CD/DVD drive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure why are you doing it but, just in case it is an attempt of copy protection remember the old (ancient) [subst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subst) in MS-DOS.

Just keep in mind that using Application.ExecutablePath and DriveInfo can be forged...